# Cassandra nodes working alone when network is disconnected

Tags: architecture, cassandra, bigdata

I have to face a complex requisite in my design for cassandra cluster and I dont know if it is possible. 
My client wants to have a redundant cassandra cluster but one of the problems faced is that sometimes the nodes become standalone for some network problems. [image: cassandra crazy architecture]

Having this picture is easier to explain. Imagine the network goes down... I want to still saving data from data emisor 2 to cassandra node 2 like standalone server(they are in the same computer).  There is any option for save only in the cassandra node 2 the some certain tables (the tables creates by data emisor2).

The reason this crazy architecture is because all is in a industrial environment where all machines can work separably.

Comment: What happens if C* node1 crashes: Data emisor 1 is not able to work anymore?

Comment: What's the purpose of node5? Does it have a replica of all other nodes?

Comment: If node1 crash data emisor1 will not save the data but the machine still working. There is another option to connect for example data emisor1 to node1 and node2 in order to avoid this problem. Another options is put JMS system like HorneQ, RabbitMQ or Kafka to buffering the petitions and waiting for node goes up.

Comment: The purpose of node 5 is to have a powerfull machine that can backup all data and could be for example a node6 machine in a external data center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a multi-datacenter cluster with NetworkTopologyStrategy, where every data emitter will write data to a local datacenter nodes. Your emitters will have to be forced to write data only to a specific datacenter through the driver configuration. The consistency levels will need to be `LOCAL_ONE`, `LOCAL_QUORUM`, in other words they should only seek a response from a local DC, and let the replication distribute data across the remaining DCs. This will ensure that if the local DC/emitter are not connected to the rest of the cluster, the writes are still coming through, and when the network connectivity is restored, all data is replicated to the rest of the DCs, most likely via a manual repair job.

In a degenerated case, each of these datacenters can consist of a single node. Of course for single node datacenters the replication factor will be 1 in each datacenter which is always dangerous and may lead to data loss if a single node dies hard.

Comment: Thank you it was so helpfull, do you think that will be possible to have only certain tables for node1 (data from sensors adquired in data emisor 1) and in the central node 5 have all the data from all the nodes?

Comment: If in your design each data emitter writes to a dedicated set of tables, you can create separate keyspaces for each emitter. For example emitter 1 writes data to a keyspace1 which replicates only locally to DC1 and to a central DC5 (I call them DC because in my model they are DCs). Similar with emitter 2 - keyspace2 locally and DC5. In this case local nodes will have only the data they own, and DC 5 will have keyspaces 1 through N with all data from them.

Comment: Your explanation open me a lot of differences ways to work , thank you!! One more question if you can reply. There is someway automatic to pass data from one keyspace to another?
imagine save in the c* node2 the data recorded from data emisor 2 (this will be a keyspace iwth c*node5) but save there only the last week data and then flush to a big server (node5 or other) to have all the database together and free the data emisor2 deleting old data.node2 is in a control panel(machinery l) not so much powerfull computer and the other node5 will be in the server center

Comment: You will need to use tools like hadoop or spark for these types of jobs